# Prediction.io app creating fail on SecureRandom method because table events_1 does not exit

Tags: predictionio

I got the error "The table pio_event:events_1 doesn't exist yet" trying to create a new app.

$ pio app new myapp

Console log:

```
[INFO] [HBLEvents] The table pio_event:events_1 doesn't exist yet. Creating now...
[INFO] [App$] Initialized Event Store for this app ID: 1.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 
java.security.SecureRandom.getInstanceStrong()Ljava/security/SecureRandom;
at io.prediction.data.storage.AccessKeys$class.generateKey(AccessKeys.scala:66)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is Java 7 on virtual machine, so we need to update to Java 8.

Steps to solve:

1) sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java

2) sudo apt-get update

3) sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer

4) sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-unlimited-jce-policy

So, run the command to create a new app (pio app new myapp). If you want to use the same name, you will need to delete it before.

Comment: Thanks for sharing Rafael.!! You can mark this as correct.